# print matrix nicely using pandas python appearance of exception

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matrix

I am trying to print matrix nicely using pandas.
But I have a problem
I have this matrix:

```
[[  0  -2  -4  -6  -8 -10]
 [ -2   1  -1  -3  -5  -7]
 [ -4  -1   2   0  -2  -4]
 [ -6  -3   0   1   1  -1]
 [ -8  -5  -2  -1   0   2]]
```

That I filled with this code:

```
def NW(s1,s2,match = 1,mismatch = -1, gap = -2):
    penalty = {'MATCH': match, 'MISMATCH': mismatch, 'GAP': gap} #A dictionary for all the penalty valuse.
    n = len(s1) + 1 #The dimension of the matrix columns.
    m = len(s2) + 1 #The dimension of the matrix rows.
    al_mat = np.zeros((m,n),dtype = int) #Initializes the alighment matrix with zeros.

    #Scans all the first rows element in the matrix and fill it with "gap penalty"
    for i in range(m):
        al_mat[i][0] = penalty['GAP'] * i
        p_mat[i][0] = 'V'
    #Scans all the first columns element in the matrix and fill it with "gap penalty"
    for j in range (n):
        al_mat[0][j] = penalty['GAP'] * j
    #Fill the matrix with the correct values.
    for i in range(1,m):
        for j in range(1,n):
            di = al_mat[i-1][j-1] + Diagonal(s1[j-1],s2[i-1],penalty) #The value for match/mismatch -  diagonal.
            ho = al_mat[i][j-1] + penalty['GAP'] #The value for gap - horizontal.(from the left cell)
            ve = al_mat[i-1][j] + penalty['GAP'] #The value for gap - vertical.(from the upper cell)
            al_mat[i][j] = max(di,ho,ve) #Fill the matrix with the maximal value.(based on the python default maximum)

    return al_mat
```

I want the matrix to look like this:

```
     T  C  G  C  A
  0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10
T -2  1 -1 -3 -5 -7
C -4 -1  2  0 -2 -4
C -6 -3  0  1  1 -1
A -8 -5 -2 -1  0  2
```

or like this:

```
      T  C  G  C  A
  [0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10]
T [-2  1 -1 -3 -5 -7]
C [-4 -1  2  0 -2 -4]
C [-6 -3  0  1  1 -1]
A [-8 -5 -2 -1  0  2]
```

I was trying to write this code:

```
import pandas as pd
col1 = [' ', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A']
col2 = [' ', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A']
df = pd.DataFrame(mat,index = col2, columns = col1)
print df
```

But I"v got this error:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(mat,index = col2, columns = col1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 163, in __init__
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 224, in _init_ndarray
    return BlockManager([block], [columns, index])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 237, in __init__
    self._verify_integrity()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 313, in _verify_integrity
    union_items = _union_block_items(self.blocks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 906, in _union_block_items
    raise Exception('item names overlap')
Exception: item names overlap
```

So it's worked only when I changed 1 letter, so I got:

```
       T   B   G   C   A  
   0   -2  -4  -6  -8  -10
T  -2  1   -1  -3  -5  -7 
C  -4  -1  2   0   -2  -4 
C  -6  -3  0   1   1   -1 
A  -8  -5  -2  -1  0   2
```

But still the layout of the matrix is not quite well.
 How can I fix those problems?

Comment: what does `mat` look like and where is it coming from? I tried this setting it` to `mat = np.random.randn(5,6)` (I imported numpy to get a dummy data set) and it worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print numpy matrix nicely with text headers - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738174/how-to-print-numpy-matrix-nicely-with-text-headers-python)

Comment: Mat is the matrix:     
 [  0  -2  -4  -6  -8 -10]
 [-2  1 -1 -3 -5 -7]
 [-4 -1  2  0 -2 -4]
 [-6 -3  0  1  1 -1]
 [-8 -5 -2 -1  0  2]

Comment: Edit your question so it includes what the matrix you're inputting looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the matrix that you've provided, I'm going to guess that your problem is that the matrix you are trying to use doesn't include commas and this is why you're getting errors. Try setting  `mat` to equal:

```
[[0,-2,-4,-6,-8,-10],
 [-2,1,-1,-3,-5,-7],
 [-4,-1,2,0,-2,-4],
 [-6,-3,0,1,1,-1],
 [-8,-5,-2,-1,0,2]]
```

Comment: Can you include in your code what exactly you're doing with numpy then? Will make it a lot clearer!

Comment: It's complicate, Because it's actually the needlemam wantch algorithm.
But I hope it will be understood.